# Find reviews left by a user on Google Places

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, google-authentication

I'm looking to add a feature in my web app that will determine whether a person has left a review on a specific Google Places listing.  I want to verify that (1) user X left a review on the listing and (2) that the person I'm dealing with is user X.

I'm looking at the Google Places API, found here, but the most information I can find is on a simple rating.

Any leads on which API to use to find reviews left by users on Google Places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, there isn't a way to do this through an API, since there is so much risk of user reviews solicited by incentives.  Google is one of the least picky review-collecting organizations, but they still try to deter biased reviews.

In other words, don't do this....